# Improve If statement for textbox checking

Tags: c#, optimization, text, if-statement, textbox

I'm making a c# login system, connected with MySQL, and so far its going pretty good. How can I make this piece of code better? Its so much code.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxUsername.Text))
{
    //Focus box before showing a message
    textBoxUsername.Focus();
    MessageBox.Show("Enter your username", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    //Focus again afterwards, sometimes people double click message boxes and select another control accidentally
    textBoxUsername.Focus();
    return;
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPassword.Text))
{
    textBoxPassword.Focus();
    MessageBox.Show("Enter your password", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    textBoxPassword.Focus();
    return;
}
```

Comment: If this code is working as is, and you're just looking for ways to improve it, this question should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- also, the question doesn't appear to relate to MySQL at all.

Comment: Belongs on CodeReview StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply move it to as a common logic and reuse the code as following.

```
       private bool IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(TextBox textBox, string messageString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(messageString, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Just called with like this:

```
 bool isValidateSuccess = IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(textBoxUsername, "Enter your username") ?  IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(textBoxPassword, "Enter your password") :false ;

    if(isValidateSuccess)
    {
    // Then check with the database with entered credential is valid or not 
    }
    else
    return;
```

Comment: if (isValidateSuccess)
                {
                    //Logged in
                    loggedInAs = username_textBox.Text;
                    this.Hide();
}

like that then right?

Comment: nope you wrong buddy.i updated my answer.just look @ it

Comment: Ah thanks man, im new to this forum, and i have no idea how stuff works around here haha :D

Answer (score 0):

You could make a private function, something like:

```
private bool isValidTextBox(TextBox box, string message)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
    {                
        MessageBox.Show(message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
        box.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, use that function like:

```
if(!isValidTextBox(textBoxUsername, "Enter your username"))
     return;
else if(!isValidTextBox(textBoxPassword, "Enter your password"))
     return;
```

Comment: using this code base got 2 message boxes.

Comment: Thanks man :D but how do i get to ''return;'' when i got this outer method?

Comment: I updated it to return a boolean that you can use to decide to return in the calling function.